# Python threading: tracking threads even after application is restarted?

Tags: python, multithreading, object

Is there a way to track if thread is running by using some kind of ID/reference of thread object so I would know if thread is really running at some specific time.

I have functionality that starts manufacturing processes on application in threaded mode. If there are no server restarts and nothing goes wrong, then everything completes normally in a background.

But if for example server is restarted,and at the time any of the threads were running, well they are killed, but production of some order is stuck in running state, because it is changed only after thread is complete.

I was thinking of some scheduler that would check those production orders and if it won't find related thread for running production order, then it assumes it is dead and has to be restarted.

But how can I make it track properly?

I have this code:

```
from threading import Thread

def action_produce_threaded(self):
    thread = Thread(target=self.action_produce_thread)
    thread.start()
    return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}

def action_produce_thread(self):
    """Threaded method to start job in background."""
    # Create a new database cursor.
    new_cr = sql_db.db_connect(self._cr.dbname).cursor()
    context = self._context
    job = None
    with api.Environment.manage():
        # Create a new environment on newly created cursor.
        # Here we don't have a valid self.env, so we can safely
        # assign env to self.
        new_env = api.Environment(new_cr, self._uid, context)
        Jobs = self.with_env(new_env).env['mrp.job']
        try:
            # Create a new job and commit it.
            # This commit is required to know that process is started.
            job = Jobs.create({
                'production_id': context.get('active_id'),
                'state': 'running',
                'begin_date': fields.Datetime.now(),
            })
            new_cr.commit()
            # Now call base method `do_produce` in the new cursor.
            self.with_env(new_env).do_produce()
            # When job will be done, update state and end_date.
            job.write({
                'state': 'done',
                'end_date': fields.Datetime.now(),
            })
        except Exception as e:
            # If we are here, then we have an exception. This exception will
            # be written to job our job record and committed changes.
            # If job doesn't exist, then rollback all changes.
            if job:
                job.write({
                    'state': 'exception',
                    'exception': e
                })
                new_cr.commit()
            new_cr.rollback()
        finally:
            # Here commit all transactions and close cursor.
            new_cr.commit()
            new_cr.close()
```

So now at part where `job` is created, it can stuck when something goes wrong. It will stuck at 'running' state, because it won't be updated in database anymore.

Should I use some singleton class that would track threads through their lifetime, so some cronjob that is run periodically, could check it and decide which threads are really running and which were killed unexpectedly?

P.S. probably there is some good practice for doing it, if so, please advice.

Comment: I think that if your script is completely obliterated (let's say with a `kill -9`) the only way you have to know the state of the threads is if those threads have been writing their progress... somewhere (file, database...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by writing singleton class. Now it tracks live threads and if server is restarted, all references to live threads will disappear and I won't find it anymore (only newly started will be found). So I will know for sure which threads are dead and can be safely restarted and which can not.

I don't know if this is the most optimal way to solve such problem, but here it is:

```
class ObjectTracker(object):
    """Singleton class to track current live objects."""

    class __ObjectTracker:
        objects = {}

        @classmethod
        def add_object(cls, resource, obj):
            """Add object and resource that goes it into class dict."""
            cls.objects[resource] = obj

        @classmethod
        def get_object(cls, resource):
            """Get object using resource as identifier."""
            return cls.objects.get(resource)

        @classmethod
        def pop_object(cls, resource):
            """Pop object if it exists."""
            return cls.objects.pop(resource, None)

    instance = None

    def __new__(cls):
        """Instantiate only once."""
        if not ObjectTracker.instance:
            ObjectTracker.instance = ObjectTracker.__ObjectTracker()
        return ObjectTracker.instance

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Return from singleton instance."""
        return getattr(self.instance, name)

    def __setattr__(self, name):
        """Set to singleton instance."""
        return setattr(self.instance, name)
```

P.S. this was used as starting example for my singleton: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html#id4